# Column header with @query_no_truncate parameter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sp-send-dbmail

I am trying to email a csv using sp_send_dbmail but one of the column values are truncating at 255 characters. So I used the @query_no_truncate parameter to display the full column value in the csv file, it works but omitted the column header.

Is there a way to keep both column header and full column value in the csv file, please?

I tried query_no_truncate parameter

Comment: This behaviour explicitly [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16): *"When set, query results don't include column headers."* Honestly, I find that you're better off using *something else* to send the emails out; dbmail is not a replacement to a good reporting tool.